# Barplot with 3 categorical variable

Tags: r, plot

I have a data like this:

```
data <- data.frame(Comp = factor(rep(2003:2004, each = 8)), 
                   Cat = rep(letters[1:4], 4), 
                   Type = rep(c('Free','Used'), each = 4), 
                   Count = trunc(rnorm(16,30,2)))
```

And I need something like a `barplot` with `beside = TRUE` and `beside = FALSE` (`TRUE` for `Cat` and `Comp`, and `FALSE = Type`).

With this data, it will result a plot with 8 columns (Interaction of `Comp` with `Cat` (`Comp = 2003 + Cat = A ; Comp = 2003 + Cat = B ; ... ; Comp = 2004 + Cat = D`)), each one with 2 stacked columns (the levels of `Type` (`Free` and `Used`)) for `Count` variable.

Any tip how can I do this kind of plot? I tried to do an example in EXCEL, but I failed on it too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similarly in `ggplot2`:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=interaction(Cat, Comp), y=Count, fill=Type)) +   
  geom_bar(position='stack', stat='identity')
```

To group on an additional variable (or two) you can use `facet_wrap` or `facet_grid`.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=Cat, y=Count, fill=Type)) +   
  geom_bar(position='stack', stat='identity') +
  facet_wrap( ~ Comp)
```

Comment: Same question: You know if there is any option to group the bars of `Cat` for each `Comp`? Like this: `barplot(VADeaths, beside = TRUE)`

Comment: Exactaly! One last question: There is an easy way to write the value in the middle of each bar?

Comment: Please try not to amend questions with more and more questions :)  take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14941940/r-stacked-bar-graph-plotting-geom-text).  While not answered, Joran's comment should make it clear whats needed.

Answer (score 4):

In `lattice`:

```
 barchart(Count~interaction(Cat,Comp),groups=Type,data=data,auto.key=T,stack=T)
```

[image]

Another way to group, from the comment:

```
barchart(Count~Cat|factor(Comp),groups=Type,data=data,auto.key=T,stack=T)
```

[image]

Comment: Almost there! You know if there is any option to group the bars of `Cat` for each `Comp`? Like this: `barplot(VADeaths, beside = TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks dude! One last question: There is an easy way to write the value in the middle of each bar?