# R stacked bar graph plotting geom_text

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot a stacked bar graph in R using ggplot. I also want to include percentage in each piece of bars for that piece. I tried to follow the posts [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12386005/r-stacked-percentage-bar-plot-with-percentage-of-binary-factor-and-labels-with), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653268/adding-labels-to-ggplot-bar-chart), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8243621/stacked-bar-graph-labels-with-ggplot2) but the values are not exactly in their respective blocks. My data is a file in [dropbox](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/105195130/Input.txt).

My code is as follows:

```
f<-read.table("Input.txt", sep="\t", header=TRUE)

ggplot(data=f, aes(x=Form, y=Percentage, fill=Position)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity", colour="black") + 
    geom_text(position="stack", aes(x=Form, y=Percentage, ymax=Percentage, label=Percentage, hjust=0.5)) + 
    facet_grid(Sample_name ~ Sample_type, scales="free", space="free") + 
    opts(title = "Input_profile", 
         axis.text.x = theme_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, size = 8, colour = "grey50"), 
         plot.title = theme_text(face="bold", size=11), 
         axis.title.x = theme_text(face="bold", size=9), 
         axis.title.y = theme_text(face="bold", size=9, angle=90),
         panel.grid.major = theme_blank(), 
         panel.grid.minor = theme_blank()) + 
    scale_fill_hue(c=45, l=80)

ggsave("Output.pdf")
```

The output is-

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your help and time!

Comment: Think about the y value you're giving to `geom_text`. It is the _height_ of each bar segment. You need to do some arithmetic to calculate the midpoint (or top, or whatever) of each bar segment, add that as a separate variable and use it as the y variable in `geom_text`. The function `cumsum` may be helpful.

Comment: Something like this will calculate the y positions for the labels at the midpoint of each bar segment: `f <- ddply(f, .(Form, Sample_name, Sample_type), transform, pos = (cumsum(Percentage) - 0.5 * Percentage))` (requires plyr), then the `geom_text` statement should be: `geom_text(aes(x=Form, y=pos, label=Percentage))`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you're using an older version of `ggplot2`. Because with your code modified for ggplot2 v 0.9.3, I get this:

```
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Form, y = Percentage, fill = Position))
p <- p + geom_bar(stat = "identity", colour = "black")
p <- p + geom_text(position = "stack", aes(x = Form, y = Percentage, ymax = Percentage, label = Percentage, hjust = 0.5))
p <- p + facet_grid(Sample_name ~ Sample_type, scales="free", space="free")
p <- p + theme(plot.title = element_text("Input_profile"), 
         axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, size = 8, colour = "grey50"), 
         plot.title = element_text(face="bold", size=11), 
         axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold", size=9), 
         axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold", size=9, angle=90),
         panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
         panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
p <- p + scale_fill_hue(c=45, l=80)
p
```

[image: ggplot2_text_placement]

You see that the text objects are normally placed properly. There are places where the bars are just too short so that the numbers overlap. You can also play with the `size` parameter.

To rectify that, you could do something like this to add up the numbers by yourself.

```
df <- ddply(df, .(Form, Sample_type, Sample_name), transform, 
      cum.perc = Reduce('+', list(Percentage/2,cumsum(c(0,head(Percentage,-1))))))

p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Form, y = Percentage, fill = Position))
p <- p + geom_bar(stat = "identity", colour = "black")
p <- p + geom_text(aes(x = Form, y = cum.perc, ymax = cum.perc, label = Percentage, hjust = 0.5), size=2.7)
p <- p + facet_grid(Sample_name ~ Sample_type, scales="free", space="free")
p <- p + theme(plot.title = element_text("Input_profile"), 
         axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, size = 8, colour = "grey50"), 
         plot.title = element_text(face="bold", size=11), 
         axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold", size=9), 
         axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold", size=9, angle=90),
         panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
         panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
p <- p + scale_fill_hue(c=45, l=80)
p
```

This gives:

[image: ggplot2_facet_text_final]

Answer (score 5):

Here a solution using `barchart` from lattice.

[image]

```
library(latticeExtra)
barchart(Percentage~Form|Sample_type*Sample_name,data=dat,
         groups =Position,stack=T,
         panel=function(...){
           panel.barchart(...)
           ll <- list(...)
           keep <- !is.na(ll$groups[ll$subscripts])
           x <- as.numeric(ll$x[keep])
           y <- as.numeric(ll$y[keep])
           groups <- as.numeric(factor(ll$groups)[ll$subscripts[keep]])
           for (i in unique(x)) {
               ok <- x == i
               ord <- sort.list(groups[ok])
               pos <- y[ok][ord] > 0
               nok <- sum(pos, na.rm = TRUE)
               h <- y[ok][ord][pos]
               panel.text(x = rep(i, nok),y = cumsum(h)-0.5*h,
                          label = h,cex=1.5)
             }
         },
         auto.key = list(columns = 5), 
         par.settings = ggplot2like(n = 5),
         lattice.options = ggplot2like.opts())
```